# KendoUI autocomplete server filtering with .net Core and no odata

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement server filtering in a .net Core mvc web app. MVC core does not support Odata out of the box and i cannot implement it.

Autocomplete seems to send query filtering along the request for data as a querystring. The querystring is a multidimensional array format.

How can i extract the value i need to filter from this querstring that looks something like:

filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=l6j&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=contains&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BignoreCase%5D=true&filter%5Blogic%5D=and"

filter[filters][0][value]=l6j&filter[filters][0][operator]=contains&filter[filters][0][field]=&filter[filters][0][ignoreCase]=true&filter[logic]=and

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this
var searchValue =  Request.Query["filter[filters][0][value]"];